# What tools or way to start a web project

Tags: web-development, development-process, web-framework

I am a sandwich training student in a company that has a little informatics service who develop web app
Until today, they work with simple php, a little CSS and no version control. So, the code becomes unmaintainable.

The project manager would like to use php object, and i am the only one with some knows in it. But i am still a beginner with no experience in web dev, and after some search i am afraid to building a php MVC alone.

So my question is : Should i convince the team to start using a framework like symfony ( i'm feeling ok to use it ) with the big change it impose to the team, or simply bring a better work structure with version control and tools like an ORM ?

Thanks for your help

EDITED : with the hope it's now understandable

Comment: Boy does this question need editing or what!

Comment: @Gaurav: I say go for it?

Comment: @Htbaa Where to start?

Comment: @Gaura what's the problem with my question ? Be contructive, explain your think

Comment: @Gaurav Yes, that's hard to say.

Comment: @canardman your question is hard to follow because of your bad English. Could you re-read your question and try to correct your grammar?

Comment: @canardman As I said earlier the question is written incorrectly, I would have edited it but I sincerely don't understand what is written.

Comment: @Gaurav @Htbaa ok that's clear now. English is not my native language. I will correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to change 2 thing technology and process. My advice is not to change them at once ,there is a real change this is a to big step for the team resulting in a fall back to the old habits. I would recommend to start with the process and introduce version control. In this way changes are better traceable and when changing the technology you can fall back on source control when needed.